# PYTHON SQLITE3: randomly select fields which when fetched don't exceed 10

Tags: python, select, random, sqlite

I'm a beginner in python. I have a database with song titles, artist, genre and song lengths. I would like my program to automatically generate a text file which contains songs (and their database data) whose song length does not exceed 10 (minutes) and/or contains songs with only a specified genre.

My database containing the songs:
[image: img]

I know all about **.fetchall** and **.fetchone** and **SELECT** **statements** but I'm still struggling a lot to even get a start on this program because I do not know how to apporach it.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("songs.db")
c = conn.cursor()

genres = ['Pop', 'Hip-Hop', 'House']
user_length = int(input("What's will be maximum time limit of your playlist?"))

while user_length < 2.6:
    user_length = int(input("That length is too small! Try a higher time limit!"))

user_genre = str(input("What genre do you want your playlist based on?"))

while user_genre not in genres:
    user_genre = str(input("You can only choose Pop, Hip-Hop or House..."))



conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: How much do you know about select statements? Just the statement:

SELECT * FROM song_list WHERE song_length<10.0 AND genre=='Pop';

(obviously substituting a variable in there for "Pop") should get you most of the way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know using AND was possible. However I've tried that but what I wanted was to  SELECT a number of random songs whose song length when added doesn't exceed 10.0 which didn't work when using '<10.0'.

Comment: Are you saying that when running it you weren't getting a random value (expected, that's a little bit more involved) or that you weren't getting a list restricted to songs with length less than 10.0?

Comment: When running it I got every song under 10 but am not sure how to work it with the random module to fetch random songs that whose song length when added doesn't exceed 10.0. So kind of like creating a playlist which doesn't last longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh, okay, I was misunderstanding what you were getting at. If you've got a relatively short list, you could pull them all into a list and use `choice()` to grab one at random and then check to see if the total length is less than 10 or not. If it is, add the choice to your list. Otherwise skip it and pick another.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like it would work, thanks!